# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout is it possible to create a PinterestLayout?

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Can i use `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` to create a Pinterest / Waterflow like layout?

the closes was with

```
func buildLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {

    // cells
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(10), heightDimension: .estimated(10))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .estimated(10))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 3)
    group.interItemSpacing = .flexible(10)

    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.interGroupSpacing = 10

    let configuration = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
    configuration.scrollDirection = .vertical
    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section, configuration: configuration)

}
```

but i cannot figure out how to remove the space under each item[image]